# How to disable dragging of splitpane divider in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I have a splitpane which is divided into 4 different AnchorPanes. So there are 3 dividers and I need to set the dividers at a predefined size. I'm doing that using,

```
leftSplitPane.setDividerPositions(0.04f, 0.4f, 0.86f);
```

However in the UI, the dividers are still draggable. I need to disallow dragging of these dividers. I tried `ResizableWithParent` in SceneBuilder. But it doesn't work. I also tried to bind the anchorpane to splitpane like this, but it seems wrong.

```
leftAnchorPane.maxWidthProperty().bind(leftSplitPane.widthProperty().multiply(1));
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Why do you use splitpane if you don't to want to drag the divider?

Comment: I need to separate out the 4 components. There must be a divider to distinguish them.

Comment: You can always add them to GridPane or some other layout which suits your need and show the borders.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha, I have many components inside each of the 4 components. Fitting them inside a grid pane is a hilarious task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to set the divider position to fixed value on its change listener:

```
final double pos[] =
{
    0.3f, 0.6f, 0.9f
};

sp.setDividerPositions( pos );

for ( int i = 0; i < sp.getDividers().size(); i++ )
{
    final int ind = i;
    SplitPane.Divider divider = sp.getDividers().get( i );
    divider.positionProperty().addListener(
            ( ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue ) ->
            {
                divider.setPosition( pos[ind] );
            } );
}
```

---

Implicit full example:

```
@Override
public void start( Stage primaryStage )
{
    SplitPane sp = new SplitPane();
    final StackPane sp1 = new StackPane();
    sp1.getChildren().add( new Button( "Button One" ) );
    final StackPane sp2 = new StackPane();
    sp2.getChildren().add( new Button( "Button Two" ) );
    final StackPane sp3 = new StackPane();
    sp3.getChildren().add( new Button( "Button Three" ) );
    sp.getItems().addAll( sp1, sp2, sp3 );

    final double pos[] =
    {
        0.04f, 0.4f, 0.86f
    };

    sp.setDividerPositions( pos );

    for ( int i = 0; i < sp.getDividers().size(); i++ )
    {
        final int ind = i;
        SplitPane.Divider divider = sp.getDividers().get( i );
        divider.positionProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed( ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue )
            {
                divider.setPosition( pos[ind] );
            }
        });
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene( sp, 400, 400 );
    primaryStage.setScene( scene );
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: It says "This lambda expression refers to the missing type ObservableValue"

Comment: syntax error. I'm using JDK 1.8 only. I have used lambda expressions like event -> System.out.println(). That works

Comment: It seems to be an Eclipse's problem. There is no such error on Netbeans. Can you convert the lambda to old fashion styled code and try again.

Comment: @NaveenBharadwaj, see full example.

Comment: I have anchor panes instead of stack panes. does it matter?
because your example works. but the same code in my application doesn't

Comment: @NaveenBharadwaj, no it shuold not do a matter. Review your code for any bindings for panes, dividers etc. and clear them.